# convert postgresql/mysql into ANSI type format Perl/Python

Tags: python, sql, perl, converters

Need to migrate several queries from another DB engine, which supports only ANSI type

So the original query:

```
SELECT time_a as t1,  time_b date 
FROM mytable T
WHERE time_a > time_b
AND date(T.time_a) = date(current_date)
AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM (current_date) )::integer = 19
ORDER BY date
```

Needs to be **re-written** as:

```
SELECT time_a as t1,  time_b "date"
FROM src.mytable T
WHERE time_a > time_b
AND cast(T.time_a as date) = cast(current_date as date)
AND to_char(current_date,'DD') = 19
ORDER BY "date";
```

The rules/statements to translate on the first query are:

1. aliases in select statement
   in case a column has a keyword as alias (eg. date), it should be enclosed by quotes date -> "date" on the select and ORDER BY clause.
2. date conversion such "date(X)" should be converted to "cast(X as date)"
3. EXTRACT statment such "EXTRACT(TIME_P FROM (X) )::integer = Y" should be converted to "to_char(X,'TIME_P_CONV') = Y"
   where TIME_P can be {DAY or MONTH}.  In case of DAY,  TIME_P_CONV will be 'DD'. In case of MONTH,  TIME_P_CONV will be 'MM'
   As the example below

I would need a script, Perl,Python, etc  that could do this kind of translations across several queries (.sql files) that could create another file with the changes.

Not sure what will be the best approach in terms of language and how to implement it, based on regular expressions, find and replace, ...

Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Have you investigated the [SQL::Translator](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Translator) module?